# Ordering Postgres jsonb in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to order by a jsonb column in rails using:

```
Stat.order("data ->'likes'->'followed_by' ASC")
```

I keep getting this error returned.

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  could not identify an ordering operator for type json
```

I can't figure out is it my formatting? The followed_by attribute is a int.

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not certain but according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

1. `->` "Get JSON object field"
2. `->>` "Get JSON object field as text"

So perhaps activerecord can't sort the `field` but can sort the `text`?

Try: `Stat.order("data ->'likes'->>'followed_by' ASC")`

Comment: For others finding this; I needed to sort by a date in a jsonb field. Using "my_column ->'date' DESC" returned a text object. This worked because by date format is "YYYY-MM-DD". But I used the object notation and it worked as an actual date: "my_column ->>'date' DESC"